# Get distinct values from a datatable or String?

Tags: sql, gridview, datatable

I have created the Datatable below which feeds a GridView on Page_Load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT DISTINCT setsTbl.setName, trainingTbl.t_date, userAssessmentTbl.o_id FROM userAssessmentTbl LEFT JOIN trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id LEFT JOIN setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id LEFT JOIN outcomesTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.o_id = outcomesTbl.o_id WHERE UserId = @UserId ORDER BY setName, t_date DESC "

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userString)
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(cmd)

   GridView1.DataSource = dt
   GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

At present it outputs values:

```
SetName t_date o_id
name1 12.12.12 1
name2 13.07.12 1
name2 15.07.12 2
name3 16.07.12 4
name3 17.07.12 3
```

I would like to get my DataTable below to output distinct rows like this:

```
SetName t_date o_id
name1 12.12.12 1
name2 13.07.12 1
name3 16.07.12 4
```

can anybody tell me hw this can be achieved?

Comment: To clarify, are you actually looking for the first distinct row for each `SetName`?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I'm after

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the earliest date for each name.  If so, you could use a Group By and the min function:

```
setsTbl.setName, Min(trainingTbl.t_date), Min(outcomesTbl.o_id)
FROM userAssessmentTbl LEFT JOIN trainingTbl ON userAssessmentTbl.tt_id = trainingTbl.tt_id 
LEFT JOIN setsTbl ON trainingTbl.s_id = setsTbl.s_id LEFT JOIN outcomesTbl 
ON userAssessmentTbl.o_id = outcomesTbl.o_id 
WHERE UserId = @UserId Group By setsTbl.setName ORDER BY setsTbl.setName
```

Comment: As stated above what I'm after is the best way to get the distinct setName from the code above (shown in the example). Be that through the sql select statement or the filtering of the DataTable.